I'm using flutter, but it crashes in recv() function in c++
Flutter's network was not available to handle fast data.
So I tried to use c++.
However, the recv() function confirmed that the program was terminated.
I'd like to know how to solve it.
Below is the flutter code I wrote. (I'm using add flutter pub add ffi)
-- solved..
The callback function must be approached with async.
var path = 'testDll.dll';
final DynamicLibrary dllfnc = DynamicLibrary.open(path);

typedef Calleback = Void Function(Int32, Pointer<Void>);
typedef NativeFnc = Void Function(Pointer<NativeFunction<Calleback>>);
typedef Fnc = void Function(Pointer<NativeFunction<Calleback>>);

class TCPRepository {

    final Fnc calledFnc = dllfnc.lookup<NativeFunction<NativeFnc>>('callbackFnc').asFunction();

    final void Function() startconn = dllfnc.lookup<NativeFunction<Void Function()>>'startconn').asFunction();
    


    void connect() {
        void nativeCallback(int result, Pointer<Void> pdata) {
            print('Received result from C++: $result');
        }
    
        final NativeCallable<Calleback> callback = NativeCallable<Calleback>.listener(nativeCallback);
        calledFnc(callback.nativeFunction);

        startconn();

        return true;
    }
}

And below is the c++ code
typedef void(*callback)(int, void*);
tcp_client* m_pclient = 0;

callback _c;

extern "C" DLLEXPORT void calledFnc(callback called)
{
    _c = called;
}


extern "C" DLLEXPORT bool startconn()
{
    std::thread([=]()
    {
        if (_c) {
            int ndata = sizeof(svr_motor_packet) * AXIS_CNT;
            int ntype = (int)0xA3;
            char* pp = new char[ndata];

            for (int i = 0; i < ndata; i++)
            {
                pp[i] = i;
            }
            _c(ntype, pp, ndata);
        }
    }).detach();
}

To using below code in flutter you can't show the error message
error: Cannot invoke native callback outside an isolate.
*important
NativeCallable.listener();

"solved" - please do not edit the question to provide a solution. Revert the edit and post an actual answer instead.
